# Ubuntu 20.04 Text splitting and screen flickering

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, kernel, graphics

I am a novice Linux user. Today, I turned on my system and found out that whenever I open any system apps (like Setting, Files, even the Terminal), a bunch of text was missing from there, and it was showing only the first four letters of every word in the app (Screenshot attached to further visualize the issue)

[image]

Please, help me to fix the issue.
Thank you all

Comment: Please edit your question and include the screenshot in the message itself.

Comment: It's already in the message.. What do you mean, exactly? sorry, I couldn't understand what you're trying to say

Comment: I've updated my question. Is the screenshot visible to you now?

Comment: This is good now.

Comment: Ok, do you know what could cause the issue? and how to solve it, please?

Comment: If you go to `Show Applications` and then `Font Manager` do all the examples show properly?

Comment: No... no matter which app I open, every app just displays the first four characters of every word, as shown in the above screenshot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the exact same condition and I was able to fix it by removing the 3rd party AMD Radeon drivers I had previously installed (and had been working fine up until this morning when I did a SW package upgrade & rebooted). I ran the following commands and rebooted. Now my display is back to normal:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

Comment: Yeah, I had already solved the issue using the exact same method. I found it on a website while searching about the problem, and I forgot to mention it here. Thanks for your answer, btw. I'll mark it as accepted so that it might be helpful to someone in the future.

Comment: I think I might have copy/pasted the wrong commands. I've updated my answer with the command I used to remove the 3rd party AMD Radeon drivers.

Comment: Seems like a lot of people are getting the same issue. So did I. @PeterVinsel 's solution worked perfectly for me. Thank you!