# Text rendering messed up somehow

Tags: fonts, 20.10

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy Gorilla (with GNOME). All was working before and somehow text rendering or such got messed up. For example, this:

[Example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnTCK.png)

If you've used IntelliJ, you would know this somewhat weird and wrong, however in case you've not, the text is weird and incomplete. For example, Sear Doub there should be Search Double Shift, and r or b should not be bold. It seems like the last character after the rendering is messed up gets bold.

Not all text is  like that though. For example Firefox works fine. Other applications all seem to work fine except their title bars are not complete, i.e. Minecraft only shows Mine and weirdly; otherwise fine though.

I don't remember making any important changes to system - maybe updates, don't remember honestly, but I want to solve this.

Another example from IntelliJ:

[Exit confirmation box being messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKh6m.png)

This not only occurs on IntelliJ but as I said impact on other applications are minimal, not like this, I've only seen their title bars getting messed up.

In the image, Conf should be Confirm exit, Are y should be Are you sure you want to exit or something, and Don' should be Don't ask next time or such, but somehow messed up like that.

I think it is something going on with fonts since it does not affect all text.

EDIT: I checked logs but there was nothing - here is font settings from gnome-tweaks

[gnome-tweaks fonts settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVLwn.png)

EDIT 2: I have discovered that this also happens on gedit, but when only on sudo mode. i.e when I open it with just gedit , the text is normal no matter if it is read-only or not. But when I open it up with sudo gedit , the text rendering becomes like the one on IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a lot of people are getting the same issue. So did I. @PeterVinsel's solution in this thread here worked perfectly for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1328913/400658 . Maybe it'll work for you too.