# Major text rendering glitch in 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, fonts

I've been dealing with a strange graphical glitch where every text field is truncated to four visible characters over most apps that come with Ubuntu. Terminal, Files, Settings, etc. I can still execute commands in Terminal, and the text is *there*, but if its longer than four characters, it becomes invisible, and the last visible character is bolded.

My web browser works fine, as does most of the apps that didn't come with the distribution except for Eclipse, which has the same behavior. This is what things look like:

[settings: about my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq7do.png)

Comment: Other occurrences of this issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328971/letters-all-scrambeld-only-4#comment2265399_1328971

Comment: Seems like a lot of people are getting the same issue. So did I. @PeterVinsel's solution in this thread here worked perfectly for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1328913/400658 . Maybe it'll work for you too.