# Xubuntu 20.04 incomplete words

Tags: xubuntu, asus, gpu-driver

a few days ago my pc has problems. Practically the words are in half and imcomplete.
how can i solve?

[image]

Comment: Does it have a problem loading or is it just broken text. They are not the same thing.

Comment: sorry. It is broken text problem.

Comment: Please correct the text of your question.

Comment: Same problem reported https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329059/on-the-desktop-xfce-displays-text-incorrectly?noredirect=1#comment2265552_1329059 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328937/ubuntu-20-04-only-shows-half-text?noredirect=1#comment2265175_1328937. Pretty sure you also have an AMD graphics card? Please confirm.

Comment: yes, same problem. Confirm.

Comment: Can Someone fix this bug? Some solution?

Comment: Same issue reported now also here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330723/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters-for-me

Comment: andrea@andrea-X501U:~$ sudo apt install ppa-purge
...
ppa-purge è già alla versione più recente (0.2.8+bzr63).
0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
andrea@andrea-X501U:~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: oibaf graphics-drivers
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: oibaf graphics-drivers