# How do I fix fonts not rendering and missing letters for me

Tags: graphics, display

hi guys how can i fix this probelm?
i'm on ubuntu 20.04
[image]

Comment: Same issue reported here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328937/ubuntu-20-04-only-shows-half-text?noredirect=1#comment2266600_1328937 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329059/on-the-desktop-xfce-displays-text-incorrectly and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329312/xubuntu-20-04-incomplete-words, all without solution thus far. Please confirm you have an AMD Graphics card.

Comment: Same issue now also here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330723/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters-for-me

Comment: ... and here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332354/ubuntu-20-04-is-showing-a-bad-text. Report your kernel (`uname -a`) and graphics (`sudo lshw -c video`). Try whether the issue is also there when booting up with an earlier version of the kernel.