# Ubuntu 20.04 is showing a bad text

Tags: 20.04, gnome

After Installing a new Ubuntu, I start text like that when I try to open the settings screen, and terminal as well!

Any idea what could be the reason for this!

[image: text not looking at ubuntu settings]

[image]

```
sudo lshw -c video
 *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV620 GL [FirePro 2260]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:51 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:efd20000-efd2ffff ioport:c000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: It is not in English ... what is the problem ?

Comment: It's English but the text is somehow cropped.  Instead of (Power) It shows(Powe) and soun instead of  sounds

Comment: Try Wayland. Does it show the same problem?

Comment: Many similar issues have been raised recently, without answers. Please add information on your graphical board to your post (use "edit") by running the following command:  `sudo lshw -c video` and pasting the output in your question (formatted as code). Also report your specific Ubuntu version: `lsb_release -a` and kernel `uname -a`

Comment: Worth trying: temporarily reboot with a previous kernel, see if the issue is also then. If not, you may want to block kernel updates for a while. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331116/pc-has-started-breaking-and-become-very-unstable?noredirect=1#comment2269930_1331116

Comment: See similar issues here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328937/ubuntu-20-04-only-shows-half-text?noredirect=1#comment2266600_1328937, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329312/xubuntu-20-04-incomplete-words and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330723/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters-for-me

Comment: Yes. It worked for me. Thank you